# Could large number in array be a timestamp to convert?

Tags: arrays, json, datetime, timestamp

I am currently reading out data that I cannot assign exactly.

The data is a list of emails with the following information:

This is what it looks like unprocessed:

```
GetMailInfos - map[0:[-45 -35 124 14 -23 103 -41 74 -71 66 67 20 -12 60 44 -101] 2:0 3:[2843521737 2843336798 2843214884 2842894940 2842726781 2842684858] 
4:[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]] 
5:[true true true true true true] 6:[4002 4300 4300 4300 4002 4300] 7:[3 3 3 3 3 3] 8:[3 3 3 3 3 3] 9:[true true true true true true] 
10:[MARKETPLACE_BUYORDER_FINISHED_SUMMARY MARKETPLACE_SELLORDER_FINISHED_SUMMARY MARKETPLACE_SELLORDER_FINISHED_SUMMARY MARKETPLACE_SELLORDER_FINISHED_SUMMARY MARKETPLACE_SELLORDER_FINISHED_SUMMARY MARKETPLACE_SELLORDER_FINISHED_SUMMARY] 
11:[637852747555964630 637852641241345990 637852580102847960 637852420676002090 637852343125116360 637852323860168170] 12:[false false false false false false] 253:168]
```

I need the timestamp of the mails and I'm sure that this is in array index 11.

- 0: Is the id of the user (guid)
- 2: unknown
- 3: Mail id
- 4: unknown
- 5: unknown
- 6: unknown
- 7: unknown
- 8: unknown
- 9: unknown
- 10: Mail type
- 11: Timestamp <<< ???
- 12: unknown
- 253: Event id

I am aware that the number is very large, so it is not seconds or maybe several values together?

The mail for **637852747555964630** normally shows this time:
**04/11/2022 - 10:25 p.m**

Does anyone here have any idea if this could be a time and if so how I can extract it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's C#'s `DateTime.Ticks`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it **is** C#'s `DateTime.Ticks` then this snippet should parse it into a usable format for you

```
string tick = "" //Your value here
DateTime date = new DateTime(long.Parse(tick));
```